# Trouble with root.after

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a GUI application in tkinter and I need the code in a function to run every 60 seconds. I have tried using the `root.after(root, function)` pause, but using this, my GUI window froze and the code in the function continued to run as I was interrupting the `root.mainloop()`. Here is a bit of the code with which I am having problems:

```
def start():
    global go
    go=1
    while go == 1:
        getclass()
        root.after(1000,func=None)

def stop():
    global go
    go=0

def getclass():
    #my code here
    print("Hello World")
```

I just want `getclass()` to run every 60 seconds when the start button is pushed. Then I want this 60 second loop to stop when the stop button is pushed.

Thank you in advance,
Sean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overthinking this: What is needed is very simple, maybe like this:

```
def start():           
    getclass()
    root.after(60000, start)    # <-- 60,000 milliseconds = 60 seconds
```

When `start()` gets called, it executes a call to `getClass()`, then sets a callback that will call itself again in 60 seconds.

**Minimal app demonstrating the use:**

```
import tkinter as tk

def getclass():
    print('hello')

def start():           
    getclass()
    root.after(60000, start)    # <-- 60,000 milliseconds = 60 seconds

root = tk.Tk()
start()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi, this works but I forgot to mention that I have to be able to stop the loop as well.

Comment: @SeanMcC. If you change the `after` call to `a = root.after(60000, start)` (and use `a` as global variable), you can cancel it with a stop button using `root.after_cancel(a)`.